# What happens if you difference a IMA?

Tags: time-series, arima, unit-root, differencing

When we over-difference a time serie, we are introducing units roots in its moving average component, hence obtaining an IMA. My question is: IMA is an integrated time serie, hence it has unit root and in order to remove them I should take differences; why doesn't it work this way and instead, taking differences of an IMA,I introduce other unit roots instead of removing them?

It would be great if you can provide some references because in the book that I'm studying this part isn't so clear...

Comment: There is a difference between a positive unit root ant a negative one.

Comment: I think that your suggestion is insightful, could you explain further?